# .htaccess all request to other file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Currently I have the following .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Which works allmost perfect.

It rewerites urls like http://domain.com/something/ to the public/index.php file, like a charm, except when it is a file, just like it should.

However http://domain.com (without any path appended) (there is no index.php in the root, so it gives a 404 at the moment) is not being rewrited, how can I change this .htaccess so it rewrites this url too?

The index file is in public/index.php I want it to load that file through the use of .htaccess

Thanks

Comment: If your htaccess file in your document root?

Answer (score 1):

I believe to rewrite the root, you can simply do something along the lines of:

```
RewriteRule ^$ location/of/root/file [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php
```

RewriteBase should prepend the rule pattern with a leading slash, forcing it to match the root path.

Untested!

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is inspired by WordPress?? It's a bad idea as it tell Apache to always check if the path is a file or a directory before redirecting.

I have something like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/(css|images|javascript)(.*) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(swf|ico|php|xml)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !robots.txt
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [PT]
```

The first condition restricts this redirect from working in specific folders.
The seconds does it for specific extensions.
You can guess what the third does :)